# Enrichment of variables within clusters

Tags: r, clustering, fishers-exact-test

I'm trying to find if some clusters in an arbitrary annotated dendrogram are enriched for a particular level of a categorical variable .
At the moment, as you can see in the picture, I'm simply calculating a Fisher'Exact Test for all the eight variables (outcome 1/0) using the within cluster occurrence of that level vs. the outisde occurrence. I define the subclusters by cutting the dendrogram at different levels, and then I plot a pink line over the most enriched cluster (I don't correct the p-values via BH at each level of cut, in order to favor bigger cluster).

[image]

My **first** question is: what would be the correct test if the levels of a variable were more than two?

My **second** question is: is there a more elegant method than cutting the tree at several levels (in my case, arbitrarily defined to 2:20) and check each time the enrichment in all the generated subgroups?

I use R, so feel free to reply by pointing me towards R packages :-)

Thanks!

Comment: Some ideas: logistic regression? Elasticnet with categorical variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your second question -- there are plenty of ways of clustering and determining the optimal number of clusters. You are using hierarchical clustering and cut the tree to get at the clusters; why not look into kmeans clustering?  I was recently also pointed to self organizing maps (SOMs). Spend some time on selecting the best clustering before starting the enrichment analysis; do not choose the clusters based on how well they are enriched.

In the case of your approach I have a problem with calculating enrichment after applying the cutting on different levels. In lay terms, if you look long enough, you will always find something. More formally, you are running tests on not independent samples; at least correct the results for multiple testing with the Bonferroni method (which does not assume the independence of the tests).

As for the enrichment test itself, I would go with Federico's suggestion and try a logistic regression approach.